# How to spyOn Angular provider factory method?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, spyon

In Jasmine, you can spyOn(object, 'function').
I am trying to spyOn a provider, which is used as "provider()".
How to spyOn it?

The provider looks like this:

```
providers.provider('telecom', function() {
    this.$get = function() {
        return function() {
            return 'something';
        }
    }
}
```

In controller, it would be used like this:

```
controllers.controller('ctrl', function(telecom) {
    var isp = telecom();
});
```

For object.method(), we can spyOn(object, 'method').
What about provider()?

I've googled and can not find anything helpful.
I tried spyOn(provider), but I got error saying "undefined() method does not exist".

I even try to mock the provider, but didn't success. (http://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [createSpy](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpy%3C/code%3E):

```
describe('Describe', function() {

  var $scope, createController;

  var telecomSpy = jasmine.createSpy('telecomSpy');

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
      $controller('MyController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        telecom: telecomSpy
      });
    };
  }));

  it('It', function() {

    expect(telecomSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    createController();

    expect(telecomSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/bdGZtOKV9mewQt9hteDo?p=preview